# Is it possible to compile CefSharp with a own compiled Chromium Embedded?

Tags: c++, cefsharp

Hello People of Stackoverflow,

I was wondering if it was possible to compile a CefhSharp source code with a own Compiled Chromium Embedded ?

Thanks.

Comment: I could find CefSharp with Google, but what does "a own Compiled Chromium Embedded" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instructions here:

https://github.com/ataranto/CefSharp/wiki/Building-CefSharp